# Schedule Twillio messages on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, twilio, google-cloud-scheduler, google-cloud-tasks

What I want to achieve is that once I receive a message via Twilio I want to schedule a reply to it after exactly 5 minutes. I am using Google Cloud Functions to generate the replies, but I'm not sure how to schedule it. I have gone through Cloud tasks, Pub/Sub and Scheduler but I'm still confused as to how to achieve it. I am using Python.

What I am thinking is the following workflow: Twilio -> cloud function receives the message and sets a task for after 5 minutes o-> another cloud function is invoked after 5 minutes. I am stuck as to how to schedule it after 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

In AWS you would use SQS in combination with [delay queues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-delay-queues.html) which makes this very convenient.

Google Cloud Pub/Sub being the equivalent to AWS SQS doesn't support any sort of delay so you would need to use Google Cloud Tasks.

When [creating a task](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks) you can specify a [schedule time](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues.tasks#Task) which identifies the time at which the task should be executed:

> scheduleTime   string (Timestamp format)
>
> The time when the task is scheduled to be attempted or retried.

Quick example code copy & pasted from the Google documentation leaving out non-relevant bits and pieces:

```
from google.cloud import tasks_v2
from google.protobuf import timestamp_pb2
import datetime
[...]
client = tasks_v2.CloudTasksClient()
parent = client.queue_path(project, location, queue)
in_seconds = 5*60  # After 5 minutes...
d = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=in_seconds)
timestamp = timestamp_pb2.Timestamp()
timestamp.FromDatetime(d)
task = {
    "http_request": {
        "http_method": tasks_v2.HttpMethod.POST,
        "url": url,
        "schedule_time": timestamp,
    }
}
# Need to add payload, headers and task name as necessary here...
[...]
response = client.create_task(request={"parent": parent, "task": task})
```